# Rails render form + jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have a little mistake about jQuery with a render form.

I have link_to_add_fields to add nested render.
The problem is when i add field, my jQuery stop working. I have no error, nothing just my jquery stop working.

Here is my code from helper and jquery

```
def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
  f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
end 

def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
  end   
  link_to_function(name, ("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))

end

function add_fields(link, association, content) {

var new_id = new Date().getTime();
var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")

$(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));

}
```

The jquery i try to use is the datepicker from jQuery UI.
my render :

```
<div class="field">
<div>
    <%= f.label :work_start_date %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :work_start_date, :class => 'calpicker' %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :work_end_date %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :work_end_date, :class => 'calpicker' %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= f.label :value_renovation %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :value_renovation %>
</div>

<div>
    <%= f.label :note %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :note, :rows => '3' %>
</div>

</div>
```

and my script for the class calpicker

```
jQuery(function() {

  // for PikaChoose

  $(".calpicker").datepicker();

});
```

i see a difference between my nested render after a link_to_add_field and if i set defaut view from my controller (mymodel.nestedmodel.build)

with mymodel.nestedmodel.build my class have 'hasDatepicker' with my calpicker, with my render i dont have this element in my class.

What can i do? with my firebug i see no error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem because you are adding fields after the DOM has loaded and after `$(".calpicker").datepicker();` has run so the new fields are not included to have a datepicker.

You will need to use the .live function to achieve this functionality so have a look at this article it might help: http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-ajax-and-livequery/

***Extracted and modified source:***

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('input.calpicker').live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
});
```